# LSTM error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'dim'

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm

I have the following code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

model = nn.Sequential(
          nn.LSTM(300, 300),
          nn.Linear(300, 100),
          nn.ReLU(),
          nn.Linear(300, 7),
          )

s = torch.ones(1, 50, 300)
a = model(s)
```

And I get:

```
My-MBP:Desktop myname$ python3 testmodel.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testmodel.py", line 12, in <module>
    a = model(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py", line 117, in forward
    input = module(input)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py", line 93, in forward
    return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 1688, in linear
    if input.dim() == 2 and bias is not None:
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'dim'
```

Why? The dimensions should be fine. I saw related fixes to this issue when `*input` is defined in `model.forward`, but I don't even have anything implemented yet.

/edit: WAIT, there IS a `*input`!? How can I override this?

Comment: This error is because the output of an LSTM is a tuple containing the output, hidden state, and cell state. You cannot pass this into a linear layer. You are only supposed to pass in the output of the LSTM not the hidden and cell states too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You won't be able to use a [`nn.RNN`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.RNN.html) inside a [`nn.Sequential`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Sequential.html) since `nn.LSTM` layers will output a *tuple* containing *(1)* the output features and *(2)* hidden states and cell states.

The output must first be unpacked in order to use the output features in your subsequent layer: `nn.Linear`. Something as, if your interested in the hidden states and cell states:

```
rnn = nn.LSTM(300, 300)
output, (h_n, c_n) = rnn(x)
```

You could define a custom `nn.Module` and implement a simple forward function:

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()

        self.rnn = nn.LSTM(300, 300)
        
        self.body = nn.Sequential(
          nn.Linear(300, 100),
          nn.ReLU(),
          nn.Linear(100, 7)) # <- had it set to in_features=300

    def forward(self, x):
        x, _ = self.rnn(x) # <- ignore second output
        x = self.body(x)
        return x
```

Such that:

```
>>> model = Model()
>>> s = torch.ones(1, 50, 300)

>>> model(s).shape
torch.Size([1, 50, 7])
```

Comment: Thank you! I know I had three outputs, but somehow I didn't come to mind this may cause troubles. Quick follow up question: I want to use an encoder architecture for text classification. My `[1, 50, 300]` is a sentence of length `50` where each word is embedded with dimension `300`. The encoded sequence shall be passed to the FC layer. Do I just take the last 'row' of the lstm tensor and pass it?, i.e. (not very beautiful): `rnn(s)[0][-1][-1].reshape(1,1,300)`

Comment: If `1` is your batch size, then you definitely need to set `batch_first=True` on your [nn.LSTM](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LSTM.html). So your RNN output will be `(batch, seq_len, input_size, hidden_size)`, in your case: `(1, 50, 300)`. Using `rnn(s)[0][-1][-1]` will select the prediction on the last timestep *of the last batch element*. Instead use `rnn(s)[0][:, -1]`. A cleaner way (imo) is to unpack first (*c.f* above) then take `[:, -1]` from the first *tuple* element.

Answer (score 3):

The error is because `nn.LSTM` returns your output and your model's state, which is a tuple containing the hidden state and the memory state.

You can fix it by defining your own `nn.Module` class that returns just the output of the LSTM for you.

```
class GetLSTMOutput(nn.Module):
    def forward(self, x):
        out, _ = x
        return out

model = nn.Sequential(
    nn.LSTM(300, 300),
    GetLSTMOutput(),
    nn.Linear(300, 100),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(300, 7))
```

The forward method of the `GetLSTMOutput` class is call implicitly and the output of the previous layer `nn.LSTM(300, 300)` is passed as an argument. It then returns just the output part, discarding the model's state.