# PyTorch Lightning Transfer Learning with Stacked LSTM

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, lstm, pytorch-lightning

I have trained a stacked LSTM on PyTorch Lightning with the following layers:

```
def __init__(self, n_features, hidden_size, batch_size, num_layers, dropout, learning_rate):
    super(LSTMClassifier, self).__init__()
    ...

    # Architecture Baseline
    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=n_features,
                        hidden_size=hidden_size,
                        num_layers=num_layers,
                        dropout=dropout,
                        batch_first=True)
    self.relu = nn.ReLU()
    self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, 2)
    self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()
```

and architecture:

```
def forward(self, x):
    # reshape to pass each element of sequence through lstm, and not all together
    # LSTM needs a 3D tensor
    x = x.view(len(x), 1, -1)

    out, _ = self.lstm(x)
    out = self.relu(out)
    out = self.fc(out)
    out = self.sigmoid(out)
    # reshape back to be compatible with the true values' shape
    out = out.reshape(self.batch_size, -1)

    return out
```

Now, I want to use this pre-trained model for transfer learning according to the PyTorch Lightning tutorial:

```
import torchvision.models as models


class ImagenetTransferLearning(LightningModule):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # init a pretrained resnet
        backbone = # loading the pretrained model from file
        num_filters = backbone.fc.in_features
        layers = list(backbone.children())[:-3]
        self.feature_extractor = nn.Sequential(*layers)

        # use the pretrained model for binary classification
        num_target_classes = 2
        self.classifier = nn.Linear(num_filters, num_target_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        self.feature_extractor.eval()
        with torch.no_grad():
            representations = self.feature_extractor(x).flatten(1)
        x = self.classifier(representations)
        ...
```

However, LSTM layers cannot be entered into an `nn.Sequential()` as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65906889/lstm-error-attributeerror-tuple-object-has-no-attribute-dim). So, what sort of module can I use as `feature_extractor` instead of `nn.Sequential()`?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, based on the linked question, I changed the `feature_extractor` definition as below (assuming you know the layers you want to freeze):

```
self.feature_extractor = nn.Sequential(self.layers[0], GetLSTMOutput(), self.layers[1])
```

Hopefully, this helps someone as I've been baffled for a while.